# I can't load the JQuery in phoneGap in ios uiwebview

Tags: ios, cordova

I embedded phoneGap in my UIWebView, referenced to this doc:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

And in the index.html, I write this sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                          alert(“jquery loaded”);
                          });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <button>Click me</button>
</body>
```

after the webview loaded, the "body" can be shown, but the alert can't be pop out. So the jquery.js is not loaded? Or something else is wrong?

Edit:
I added "http:" to the src, but not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
alert(“jquery loaded”);
```

to

```
alert("jquery loaded");
```

or

```
alert('jquery loaded');
```

Comment: Thank you jcesar, it works!!! How careless I am! I even didn't notice it. You are so careful!

Answer (score 1):

Add http or https to your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above should work for you.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. But it's still not working. Even I copied the jquery.js to my local folder.

Comment: Did you add Cordova file? <script type="text/javascript" src="./cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Cordova file?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                          alert(“jquery loaded”);
                          });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Also as much as phonegap uses HTML 5 it still requires a bit different style of writing your code. Everypage you make should all be in the same index page because Cordova loads at startup in your project. If you navigate away from the page Cordova needs to reload.

Comment: Hi Ben, it's still not working. I can run javascript. Not sure where is wrong.

Comment: by the way, i'm using cordova 2.5, and the cordova.plist is changed to config.xml.

Answer (score -1):

Did you copy jquery file at www forder (www/jquery.js). I use jquery too, mine is www/js/jquery.js
Try this!!!

Comment: Hi, I have put the .js under www, not work. And I tried to put it under www/js, not work either. do you also use cordavo 2.5?